# How to output game code properly

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

So I am making a snakes and ladders game. If player1 and player2 land on the same grid they must have a duel. In my game the two players must have a game of rock paper scissors. I am having trouble getting my method to return the value int win to my subprogram Begin(). The win value will tell the begin method if either Player 1 or 2 won the rock paper scissors battle.

My code:

```
public static String Begin // Recieves data from the main method
  {
// start Begin method
    int win=0;
    if(P1Position==P2Position||P2Position==P1Position){
            System.out.println("==========================================================================");                       
       System.out.println (player1+" is currently on square " + P1Position);
       System.out.println (player2+" is currently on square " + P2Position); 
       System.out.println("==========================================================================");     

        firstplay(choice1,choice2);
        determineOutcome(choice1,choice2,win);
        if(win==1){
            determineOutcome(choice1,choice2,win);
            P2Position=P1Position-P1Roll;
        }
        else{
            determineOutcome(choice1,choice2,win);
            P1Position=P2Position-P2Roll;
        }
        }
}
    public static void firstplay(int choice1,int choice2)throws IOException{//USER
            // Initializes the BufferReader for user input
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("DUEL!!!\nThe Player who wins this round of rock paper scissors will keep their spot,and the loser ther that player's old spot");
            System.out.println("1=Rock\n2=Paper\n3=Scissors\n===========");
            System.out.println(player1+" choose:");
            choice1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println(player2+" choose:");
            choice2=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if(choice1==1){
                System.out.println(player1+" chose Rock");//If user picked ROck
            }
            else if(choice1==2){
                System.out.println(player1+" chose Paper");//If user picked Paper
            }
            else if(choice1==3){
                System.out.println(player1+" chose Scissors");//If user picked Scissors
            }

            if(choice2==1){
                System.out.println(player2+" chose Rock");
            }
            else if(choice2==2){
                System.out.println(player2+" chose Paper");
            }
            else if(choice2==3){
                System.out.println(player2+" chose Scissors");
            }
        }
        public static int determineOutcome(int choice1,int choice2,int win)throws IOException{
            // Initializes the BufferReader for user input
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
            int die=0;


    //Rock vs Papaer

            if(choice2==1&&choice1==2){
                System.out.println(player1+" WON PAPER BEATS ROCK");
                System.out.println(player1+" keeps their spot");
                win=1;

            }
            else if(choice2==2&&choice1==1){
                System.out.println(player2+" WON PAPAER BEATS ROCK ");
                System.out.println(player1+" keeps their spot");
                win=0; 

            }

            //Scissors vs Paper
            else if(choice2==2&&choice1==3){
                System.out.println(player1+" WON SCISSORS BEAT PAPER ");
                 System.out.println(player1+" keeps their spot");
                win=1;
            }
            else if(choice2==3&&choice1==2){
                System.out.println(player2+" WON SCISSORS BEAT PAPER ");
                System.out.println(player2+" keeps their spot");
                win=0;
            }
            //Rock vs Scissors
            else if(choice2==3&&choice1==1){
                System.out.println(player1+" WON ROCK BEATS SCISSORS ");
                System.out.println(player1+" keeps their spot");
                win=1;
            }
            else if(choice2==1&&choice1==3){
                System.out.println(player2+" WON ROCK BEATS SCISSORS ");
                 System.out.println(player2+" keeps their spot");
                win=0;
            }
            //Ties
            else if(choice2==1&&choice1==1){
                System.out.println("YOU'VE TIED. Play once again");

            }
            else if(choice2==2&&choice1==2){
                System.out.println("YOU'VE TIED. Play once again");

            }
            else if(choice2==3&&choice1==3){
                System.out.println("YOU'VE TIED. Play once again");

            }
        return win;


        }

    }//end class
```

Output:

```
yo Rolled a 2
po Rolled a 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
==========================================================================
yo is currently on square 2
po is currently on square 2
==========================================================================
DUEL!!!
The Player who wins this round of rock paper scissors will keep their spot,and the loser ther that player's old spot
1=Rock
2=Paper
3=Scissors
===========
yo choose:
1
po choose:
3
yo chose Rock
po chose Scissors
==========================================================================
yo is currently on square 0
po is currently on square 2
==========================================================================
yo press r to roll
```

Expected:
Output:

```
yo Rolled a 2
po Rolled a 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
==========================================================================
yo is currently on square 2
po is currently on square 2
==========================================================================
DUEL!!!
The Player who wins this round of rock paper scissors will keep their spot,and the loser ther that player's old spot
1=Rock
2=Paper
3=Scissors
===========
yo choose:
1
po choose:
3
yo chose Rock
po chose Scissors
yo won rock beats scissors.
yo keeps their spot
==========================================================================
yo is currently on square 2
po is currently on square 0
==========================================================================
yo press r to roll
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the `int` value returned by the method `determineOutcome`.

```
win = determineOutcome(choice1,choice2,win);
if(win==1){
    ...
}
```

Note that is not necessary to pass `win` as a parameter to `determineOutcome()`, since you are not using its actual value. You could try this instead:

```
public static int determineOutcome(int choice1, int choice2) throws IOException
{
    // Initializes the BufferReader for user input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int die = 0;
    int win = 2; // 2 == TIE
    //Rock vs Papaer

    if (choice2 == 1 && choice1 == 2) {
        System.out.println(player1 + " WON PAPER BEATS ROCK");
        System.out.println(player1 + " keeps their spot");
        win = 1;

    } else if (choice2 == 2 && choice1 == 1) {
        System.out.println(player2 + " WON PAPAER BEATS ROCK ");
        System.out.println(player1 + " keeps their spot");
        win = 0;

    }

    //Scissors vs Paper
    else if (choice2 == 2 && choice1 == 3) {
        System.out.println(player1 + " WON SCISSORS BEAT PAPER ");
        System.out.println(player1 + " keeps their spot");
        win = 1;
    } else if (choice2 == 3 && choice1 == 2) {
        System.out.println(player2 + " WON SCISSORS BEAT PAPER ");
        System.out.println(player2 + " keeps their spot");
        win = 0;
    }
    //Rock vs Scissors
    else if (choice2 == 3 && choice1 == 1) {
        System.out.println(player1 + " WON ROCK BEATS SCISSORS ");
        System.out.println(player1 + " keeps their spot");
        win = 1;
    } else if (choice2 == 1 && choice1 == 3) {
        System.out.println(player2 + " WON ROCK BEATS SCISSORS ");
        System.out.println(player2 + " keeps their spot");
        win = 0;
    }
    //Ties
    else if (choice2 == 1 && choice1 == 1) {
        System.out.println("YOU'VE TIED. Play once again");

    } else if (choice2 == 2 && choice1 == 2) {
        System.out.println("YOU'VE TIED. Play once again");

    } else if (choice2 == 3 && choice1 == 3) {
        System.out.println("YOU'VE TIED. Play once again");

    }
    return win;

}
```

Here you are declaring a **local variable** `win`, set it (`0, 1 or 2`) in the respective conditionals and return it at the end.

**Note:** If your conditionals to determine if a player won covers all the cases, you can replace the *"Ties cases"* with an `else`:

```
//Rock vs Scissors
else if (choice2 == 3 && choice1 == 1) {
    System.out.println(player1 + " WON ROCK BEATS SCISSORS ");
    System.out.println(player1 + " keeps their spot");
    win = 1;
} else if (choice2 == 1 && choice1 == 3) {
    System.out.println(player2 + " WON ROCK BEATS SCISSORS ");
    System.out.println(player2 + " keeps their spot");
    win = 0;
}
//Ties
else {
    System.out.println("YOU'VE TIED. Play once again");
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting errors? The result is unexpected? I would recommend you to learn to debug your programs, you could use a debugger, or simply use `System.out.println` statements with helpful information, like `System.out.println("winner: " + win)` in the places you think convenient.

Comment: Could you also post the **expected output**?

Comment: @user3188122 It's very difficult to test it because I can't run it. I don't know how you defined `P1Position`, `choice1`, `player1`... I would really recommend you to read how to post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This would be help you in the future when you want to ask something else in StackOverflow.